# print row of integers from csv file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have a csv file. I just want to print the rows of the file as integers not in [ ].
My table of numbers looks like:

1 ; 0 ; 5 ; 10 ; 4 ; 3 ; 1 ; 7 ; 6 ; 11

---

1 ; 10 ; 4 ; 1 ; 1 ; 31 ; 0 ; 11 ; 0 ; 41

---

10 ; 4 ; 0 ; 12 ; 34 ; 2 ; 13 ; 3 ; 4 ; 4

---

2 ; 3 ; 6 ; 4 ; 5 ; 7 ; 8 ; 9 ; 11 ; 10

---

1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 12 ; 23 ; 24 ; 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4

---

1 ; 76 ; 3 ; 43 ; 54 ; 6 ; 5 ; 4 ; 3 ; 4

---

18 ; 12 ; 13 ; 14 ; 25 ; 34 ; 56 ; 43 ; 23 ; 23

---

34 ; 2 ; 5 ; 3 ; 3 ; 23 ; 23 ; 3 ; 2 ; 43

---

34 ; 32 ; 1 ; 5 ; 3 ; 23 ; 21 ; 3 ; 1 ; 3

---

1 ; 1 ; 2 ; 45  ; 2 ; 23 ; 1 ; 4 ; 1 ; 1

---

Now. My code looks like this.

```
import csv
with open('probeMitComma.csv','r+') as fin:
    read= csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    total = 0
    rows = list(read)
    print (rows[1],"\n",rows[2])
```

what I get is

```
['1', '10', '4', '1', '1', '31', '0', '11', '0', '41'] 
 ['10', '4', '0', '12', '34', '2', '13', '3', '4', '4']
```

I want to get those without [ ] and without ' '. I have tried with **join** (I get an error because it is with int)

beside this issue I also have another one. 
My full code looks like:

```
import csv
with open('probeMitComma.csv','r+') as fin:
    read= csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    total = 0
    rows = list(read)    #If I make this line and the one under as a comment it
    print (rows[1],"\n",rows[2])    #shows me the column that I want with the sum

    for col in read:
        print (col[0])
        total += int(col[0])
    print ("Total lautet " + str(total))
```

My real objective is to print each column with the respective sum and each row with the respective sum.

Comment: heads up, there is a glaring bug in your code: `rows = list(read)` exhausts the iterator. So when you do `for col in read:` the body of that for-loop is never executed, because `read` is done iterating.

Comment: Also, `read` returns rows... putting that in a variable called `col` is...

Comment: Convert the ints to strings : `", ".join(map(str, row[0]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking advantage of the `print()` function:

```
print(*rows[1], sep=', ')
print(*rows[2], sep=', ')
```

gives you the desired output:

```
1, 10, 4, 1, 1, 31, 0, 11, 0, 41
10, 4, 0, 12, 34, 2, 13, 3, 4, 4
```

The help of the `print()` function:

> print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>
> Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default. Optional
>   keyword arguments: file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the
>   current sys.stdout. sep:   string inserted between values, default a
>   space. end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
>   flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped. There is one issue, I lost the first row (1 ; 0 ; 5 ; 10 ; 4 ; 3 ; 1 ; 7 ; 6 ; 11) although I used print(*rows[0], sep=', ')